# Not managing to make AND operator work in bash script

Tags: shell-script

I'm trying to make a rather simple bash script where if the input is "on 1" it will execute an action and if it is "on 2" it will execute another action. I did a bit of googling about to find out how people were making the and operator work in bash scripts, I found a lot of different ways and none of them seemed to work, until I found to replace my brackets[] with parentheses().

```
#!/bin/sh
#

if (($1=="on" && $2=="1")); then
    echo $1 $2
else
    echo failure
fi
```

Once I got that far, what happens is that my script is accepting the second argument, but not the first. So if I write "off 1" the script gets executed even if $1 wasn't "on" like the if should be demanding, however if I write "on 2" the code jumps to my else statement.

How do I make it read both arguments properly instead of only the second?

Comment: `(( ))` is for numeric operations. Numbers only. You're looking for `[[ ]]`.

Comment: use for example this: if  [ $1=="on" ] && [ $2=="1" ]

Comment: Changing to [[ ]] just made things worse (it reads neither argument and always runs)

Using [] && [] gives me the same result as [[ ]]

I guess I can save myself by replacing my "on" with a "1" and using parantheses though, that helped @muru thanks :)

But I'd like to know how to do this correctly with a string and number.

Comment: Use spaces; @muru's suggestion works well here: `[[ "$1" == "on" && "$2" == 1 ]]`

Comment: Thanks @roaima, quotation marks around the $1 and $2 as well as spaces between the variables and the operators were my mistake, as well as of course that I should use brackets instead of parentheses when I'm working with strings. Your example is what worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this, as mentioned in comments, but note the spaces.

```
#!/bin/bash


if [[ "$1" == "on" && $2 -eq 1 ]]; then
    echo $1 $2
else
    echo failure
fi
```

Comment: == is not the way to compare numbers!

Comment: Sorry, corrected it.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to figure it out thanks to this comment.

The problem was that I didn't put quotation marks around the $# vars, (so $1 instead of "$1" like in your example)

And after that, the problem was that after the quotation marks were added, I needed to create a space between the "$1" and == and "on". In your example you failed on the spacing between the strings and the operator, but otherwise it worked correctly for me. If you fix it by adding the spacing I'll mark your answer as the solution :)

Comment: If you're using `[[`, you should change the she-bang to be `#!/bin/ksh` or `#!/bin/bash`. There's no `[[` in the standard `sh` language. In `sh`, you'd write `[ "$1" = on ] && [ "$2" -eq 1 ]`.

Comment: I edited, should I change the whole answer?

Answer (score 3):

Double parentheses are for numeric operations; square brackets `[]` act like boolean contexts. Double square brackets aren't portable, and will fail in `dash` and other very minimal shells. In reality, `[` is a shell builtin/POSIX utility that performs logical operations, which is why you need spaces around them. [This link](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031) has a lot more detail on the topic if you're curious.

If I were to write this, it would look more like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

# check we got the expected number of arguments
if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]; then
  echo USAGE ...
  exit
fi

if [ "x$1" = "xon" ] && [ "$2" -eq 1 ]; then
  echo "$1 $2"
else
  echo failure
fi
```

The "x" concatenation is good practice to prevent empty strings from derailing your program.

Comment: An empty string is always a valid string. That's what the "" are for. The x concat is from crippled operating systems.

Comment: the problem `x` tries to address is not about empty strings. It's about problems with values of `$1` like `!` or `-f` in pre-POSIX shells. It's not needed in modern systems.

Comment: The two separate tests `[ ... ] && [ ... ]` can often be replaced with the one `[ ... -a ... ]`